# Finding a matching date in a column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find a match of a date in a column and would like to know the simplest way to do in VBA.

This is what I have tried:

```
date1 = Sheets("Part2").Cells(i, 1).Value
Dim matchRow As Integer
matchRow = 3
While Sheets("1.A").Cells(matchRow,1).Value != date1 Then
matchRow = matchRow + 1
End While
```

I am getting a date from another sheet and would like to match it with another sheet.

Need some guidance on how to simplify this.

Comment: `!=` should be `<>` in VBA

Comment: I would use either Range.Find (may be dependent on date format settings) or WorksheetFunction.Match.  Also, declaring a variable as an Integer limits it to 32,768. Since Excel has more rows, you will return an error if you ever reference a higher numbered row.  Declare it of type Long.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work - if you set the value for 'i' to get the date to search for...

```
date1 = Sheets("Part2").Cells(i, 1).value

Sheets("1.A").Select

Cells.Find(What:=date1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Debug.Print ActiveCell & vbTab & ActiveCell.Address

If ActiveCell = date1 Then
    MsgBox "Found in: " & ActiveCell.Address
Else
    MsgBox "Not found"
End If
```